# How to use ansible to run commands through a remote server to another remote server

Tags: ansible

In our work setup , there is a `remote server B` which is accessible only via a remote server A .

- How can i run ansible commands/playbooks on remote server B through remote server A from my local system where ansible runs ,ie,
  local system --> remote server A --> remote server B
- The `remote server B` is accessible via `remote server A` through ssh . But i do not have access to the ssh keys to `remote server B`

this is what i tried to do in my inventory.yaml file based on the answer below

```
  hosts:
    remote-serverB:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: "ssh"
    ansible_user: "userB"
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p <password> ssh -W %h:%p -q userA@remote-serverA"'
```

but i get the following error from ansible

```
UNREACHABLE  {"changed": false, "msg": "EOF on stream; last 100 lines received:\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r", "unreachable": true}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via the `ansible_ssh_common_args`.

> **ansible_ssh_common_args**
>   This setting is always appended to the default command line for sftp, scp, and ssh. Useful to configure a `ProxyCommand` for a certain host (or group).

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters*</sup>

Here is an example of inventory using this configuration, given that my two servers have, as FQDN

- `remote-server-A`
- `remote-server-B`

and that the user to login to `remote-server-A` is `user-to-A`.

```
all:
  servers-needing-jump:
    hosts:
      remote-server-B:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user-to-A@remote-server-A"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @β.εηοιτ.βε , but i am getting an error . I have updated my question above with what i tried . Can you let me know what is it that i could be doing wrong . Thanks